# Generate 10 random numbers, without duplicates

Tags: actionscript-3

I have made this to generate 10 random numbers, without duplicates, but it does not work propely. Sometimes it generates duplicates, but I don't know why. Can someone please tell me what is wrong with the code, does it have something with indexOf to do?

```
var minArray:Array = new Array;
var fortsett:Boolean = true;

for(var i=0;i<10;i++) {
    while(fortsett) {
        var valgtTall=1 + Math.round(Math.random()*(34-1));
        if(minArray.indexOf(valgtTall,0) >= 0) {
            fortsett=true;
            trace(valgtTall + " er opptatt. Finner nytt...");
        }
        else {
            fortsett=false;
        }
    }
    minArray.push(valgtTall);
    trace(valgtTall);
    fortsett=true;    
}
```

Comment: This works properly for me. It never produces any duplicates.

Comment: Your code looks fine, remove this line `trace(valgtTall + " er opptatt. Finner nytt...")` which give an illusion that is generating duplicated values.

Comment: You should `trace(minArray)` to determine if there are actually duplicates once your code completes. I say there shouldn't be any, you are filtering them out by checking `indexOf()` properly.

Answer (score 0):

One **simple** and highly **inefficient** way to do this would be as such:

```
var numbers:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>();

loop: while(numbers.length < 10) {
    var rand:uint = Math.random() * 10;

    for (var i:uint = 0; i < numbers.length; ++i) {
        if(rand == numbers[i]) {
            continue loop;
        }
    }

    numbers.push(rand);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yet another way that worked pretty well for me:

```
var max:uint = 10;  // max random number
var i:int = 0;      
var l:int = 10;     // length of sequence to generate
var id:uint = 0;    // temp var for the ID
var ids:Vector.<uint> = new Vector.<uint>();

while (i < l)
{
    // generate a new random number until we found one that doesn't exist yet
    while (ids.indexOf(id) > -1) id = uint(Math.random()*max);

    // add it to the list
    ids.push(id);

    // next!
    i++;
}
```